# New to ROS - Want to get quadrocoptor or drones

Tags: ros, uav, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi -

Hobby robotics/AI builder.  I have done a bunch of projects with the NXT and some C-based programming, but I would like to get into ROS and pick up either a quadrocoptor or a set of small drone-like coptors I could use to program.  Is there a good quadcoptor that isn't too expensive for me to get started on that would be recommended for a beginner on ROS?  Also - I would like to get into swarm robotics and perhaps have 5 or 6 drones behaving in unison.  Is this something that is possible on a hobbyist's budget or is it a higher level project?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32360/new-to-ros---want-to-get-quadrocoptor-or-drones/) by [MusicMagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2226/musicmagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-04-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That question depends on what kind of budget you have but it's likely a higher level project. The cheapest quadrotor on the market at the moment is the [AR Drone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003ZVSHB0). While a lot of fun to fly they are limited and may or may not be applicable to your project. You can build something considerably more capable for about $600. I've done this by combining a [Guai 330X](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1229089) chassis (which is no longer for sale) and an [ArduPilot Mega](http://store.diydrones.com/ArduPilot_Mega_kit_p/kt-apm-01.htm). Beware that this route requires a sizable time investment to achieve programmatic control over such a device. If you are not tied to the idea of using real robots you could consider the [hector_quadrotor statck](http://www.ros.org/news/2012/03/announcement-of-hector-quadrotor-stack.html). IIRC it is a quadrotor simulator built on Gazebo and should allow you to work with a swarm.

---

Originally posted by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) with karma: 328 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2